# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable with gitlab docker and nginx-proxy docker

Tags: nginx, docker, gitlab, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

### Description:

I've set up the [nginx-proxy container](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) which works really great with one of my two docker containers. Which is just a mini go web server on `dev.MY_IP_ADDRESS.com`.

I've set it up for my [gitlab docker container](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab) as well which runs on `MY_IP_ADDRESS.com:10080` but doesn't seem to work with `gitlab.MY_IP_ADDRESS.com`

I've done the same configurations as with my web server, by setting by adding an environment variable:

```
gitlab:
  #other configs here
  environment:
   - VIRTUAL_HOST=gitlab.MY_IP_ADDERSS.com
   #more configs here
```

The only difference is that I set up my go server and nginx-proxy server in the same `docker-compose.yml` and the gitlab one uses a different `docker-compose.yml` file. Unsure if this has anything to do with it.

I've attempted to `docker-compose up` each file in a different orders to see if that was an issue.

### Error:

This is what I get when I go on gitlab.MY_IP_ADDRESS.com:

> 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
>
> nginx/1.11.8

### Question:

Why isn't the reverse proxy for `gitlab.MY_IP_ADDERSS.com` working for gitlab? Is there a conflict somewhere? It works fine on `MY_IP_ADDRESS.com:10080`

*If any logs are needed or any more information let me know. Thanks.*

Comment: Gitlab comes with its own NGINX.

Comment: @MattSchuchard yes I am aware of that, which I figure is why there is a conflict.

Comment: @rugdealer Just having the same problem, did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @Jonas unfortunately I did not. This issue was taking too much time to solve, so just using the port number atm... it's a pity.

Answer (score 0):

I completely forgot about this question, I actually found a solution which worked for me:

The problem is that your `docker-gen` is not able to find your GitLab and therefore does not generate the Nginx configuration for `gitlab.MY_IP_ADDERSS.com`.

To solve this you have three options:

1.) If you are using the solution with separate containers and launch the `docker-gen` container with the `-only-exposed` flag this might prevent it from finding GitLab. This was the issue in my case which is why I am mentioning it.

2.) In your case it will probably be because your GitLab container and your Nginx container do not share a common Docker network. Create one like `docker create network nginx-proxy` and add all your containers to it.

3.) Another solution proposed in [this issue](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/502) is to add a line `network_mode: bridge` to your GitLab container. I did not test this myself.